# Vim color scheme not displaying properly

Tags: vim, colors, xterm

I downloaded the `Dark.vim` color scheme from here: 
http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-c.html (Click on Dark.vim to see the code)

Then put it in `~/.vim/colors`.

I also did the same for `256-jungle.vim` and `af.vim`.

`:colorscheme Dark`, `:colorscheme af`, etc. all work (i.e. they change vim's syntax highlighting) but none of them look like the screenshots in the link above.

Instead, they look like this (ordered af.vim, 256-jungle.vim, Dark.vim): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixgy5.jpg

At first I thought this might be a problem with the color-settings in my terminal, so I followed tips from a "256 colors in vim" Vim wiki-doc page, which told me to add the following to my `~/.bash_profile` :

```
TERM=xterm-256color

# for enabling 256 color, as per http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim
if [ -e /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color ]; then
        export TERM='xterm-256color'
else
        export TERM='xterm-color'
fi
```

This didn't work.

Also, here's what's in my `~/.vimrc` file:

```
set tabstop=2
set t_Co=256
colorscheme 256-jungle
colorscheme Dark
syntax on
let $VIM='~/.vim/'
```

Any thoughts on what's causing this disparity between what the colorschemes "should" look like and what's actually being displayed in my terminal? I'm running Mac OS X 10.8.2.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

The Dark colorscheme you tried to use in terminal is actually a scheme for GUI (if you take a look at it's code, you'll see only 'guifg, guibg' etc. definitions). To run gui colorschemes in a terminal you can try [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) plugin.